# clear value of text area

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, jquery, jquery-selectors

I would like to clear the value of a text area.

```
<textarea style="width:850px;height:500px" id="txtEnterProject"  name="txtEnterProject">aaa</textarea>

$("#txtEnterProject").cleditor();    //set fckEditor

$("#txtEnterProject").attr("value",null);
$("#txtEnterProject").val(null);
$("#txtEnterProject").text(null);
$("#txtEnterProject").html(null);

$("#txtEnterProject").attr("value",'');
$("#txtEnterProject").val('');
$("#txtEnterProject").text('');
$("#txtEnterProject").html('');

$("#txtEnterProject").attr("value",' ');
$("#txtEnterProject").val(' ');
$("#txtEnterProject").text(' ');
$("#txtEnterProject").html(' ');
```

Any idea why none of this works?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Script:**

```
   <script type="text/javascript"> 
        function resetEditor(id) 
        {
            FCKeditorAPI.GetInstance(id).SetData('');
        }
    </script>
```

or possibly:

```
   <script type="text/javascript"> 
        function resetEditor(id) 
        {
            FCKeditorAPI.GetInstance(id).SetHTML('');
        }
    </script>
```

**Usage:**

```
resetEditor(txtEnterProject);
```

Check here for more info : [Clearing an FckEditor](http://cksource.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=7111) and here is another link: [Using FCKeditor](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/fckeditor.aspx?display=Print) (it is for .NET but it has some things regarding using Javascript to perform functions)

Hope it helps.

Comment: @Hasan this does not work (but Google Translate does)